# Dell wireless not working after upgrade

Tags: wireless, dell, broadcom, inspiron

So, the short version of my sad story is that I tried upgrade Ubuntu to 12.04 and wireless driver has stopped working. I have tried all the solutions but nothing seem to be working.

When I try to install my wireless from "**Additional Drivers**"
Its says:

> Sorry, installation of this driver failed. Please have a look at the
>   log file for details: /var/log/jockey.log

The `lspci` command gives me the following info about wireless:

```
0c:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01)
```

I have tried removing bcm drivers and reinstalling, but nothing seems to be working.
`rfkill` is good too.

Comment: Hmmm ... I have a Dell laptop, too (Studio 1535) and I get the exact same information as you when I run lspci.  And mine works!  It's running the "Broadcom STA wireless driver."

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons for that, possible cause:

> Your OS is not with all modules inserted.

Solution:

1. Type: `lsmod > list1.txt`
2. Then create a USB installer with the "Startup Disk Creator" using the ISO of your installation CD (a pen of 2GB is enough).
3. Then boot from that USB PEN and choose "Try Ubuntu" and type there: `lsmod > list2.txt` and copy this file to the same location the one above and open  both in text editor and see if there is missing modules in list1.txt.
4. To install missing modules use first `modinfo <name of the module>` after the description see if it needs dependencies and install those first if not, just copy the full path of the `ko`file and type `sudo insmod <path/file.ko>`, after all modules inserted no need for reboot things should start working fine.